# Open links from Outlook in non-default browser

Tags: microsoft-outlook, browser

I use Firefox as my default browser, but I want all links from Microsoft Outlook to be opened in Chrome. I need it because of separation - I use Firefox for one kind of work and Chrome for another.

Here the solution for a similar problem [was proposed](https://superuser.com/questions/128852/firefox-is-my-default-browser-but-i-want-links-within-outlook-email-to-open-in-ie), but I want a different browser, not a different engine for displaying pages.

Comment: As an aside: as far as I know, Outlook will always first use some IE component to check if the link exists. (That is surely true for other Office applications such as Excel [and Word](http://superuser.com/questions/41935/clicking-hyperlinks-in-email-messages-becomes-painfully-slow/42237#42237).) Only when a link gives some response, the default browser will be opened (optionally even with a changed URL, in case of a redirect response). This "Microsoft Office Discovery Protocol" *might* be a good search term when trying to solve your question...

Comment: This question was last active 4 years ago, but there have been several MS Office and Windows releases since then.  I'm upvoting the question and making some edits to see if some attention will uncover a feature in one of these new releases.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Browsermaster](http://browsermaster.codeplex.com/releases/view/34262). It's an application that lets you choose your browser each time you open a link.

Comment: Since codeplex will be shut down in July 2021, here's a preemptive internet archive version of the browsermaster page for future viewers of this question: http://web.archive.org/web/20210201193631/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=browsermaster

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, you cannot. This is a limitation that is common to the major operating systems, they offer a single application for any URL scheme. You cannot select a non-default handler. I have seen some applications allow the selection of a non-default browser or mailer (Pointcast and iPhoto come to mind), but my impression was that this was app-specific code.

The annoying thing, if you are in Mac OS, is that you can right-click ona file, and select a non-default application.