# How do I set Outlook 2016 to ignore the default web browser and always use Internet Explorer for links?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, internet-explorer-11

Outlook 2016 uses the computer's default web browser to open website links, which is fine in most cases.

The problem is, we have another Microsoft application that uses email messages to notify users when they have an outstanding action item.  The email message provides links to complete those action items.  Those links only work in Internet Explorer.

Is there a way to force links clicked in Outlook 2016 to open in a specific web browser, in this case, Internet Explorer?

Comment: May be a duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/199693/open-links-from-outlook-in-non-default-browser

Comment: May be a duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/128852/firefox-is-my-default-browser-but-i-want-links-within-outlook-email-to-open-in-ie